# Django_Hosts Import Error

Tags: python, django, python-3.5

What I'm trying to do is make the website redirect to www(eg"*example.com*" to "*www.example.com*")

I used **pip** to install **django_hosts**, and then followed the **documentation** on the website

Here is my **settings.py** file:

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'lsjz5tm#+0(99cv@mg=himl8=4w-vd^qq07jpd3d5278!hv06x'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
#    'example.com',
#    'www.example.com',
    '*',
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Reviews',
    'Contact',
    'Lessons',
    'News',
    'QNA',
    'Home',
    'About',
    'Pupils',
    'Website',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #third party
    'django_hosts'
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django_hosts.middleware.HostsRequestMiddleware'
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_hosts.middleware.HostsResponseMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
ROOT_HOSTCONF = 'mysite.hosts'
DEFAULT_HOST = 'www'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join('static'),
    )
STATIC_ROOT = ''
```

And this is my **hosts.py** file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django_hosts import patterns, host

host_patterns = patterns('',
    host(r'www', settings.ROOT_URLCONF, name='www'),
    #host(r'(\w+)', 'path.to.custom_urls', name='wildcard'),
)
```

When I run *python manage.py runserver* I get the following **error**:

*django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'mysite.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module: 'No module named 'django_hosts.middleware.HostsRequestMiddlewaredjango'; 'django_hosts.middleware' is not a package'*

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You missed a comma at the end of the first line:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django_hosts.middleware.HostsRequestMiddleware', # <-----
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```